# Attach heat sink to cpu cooler in order to decrease CPU temperature

Tags: cpu, heatsink, cooling

The best **SMALL FACTOR** cpu cooler that I have found so far is this one:

[image]

I am building a portable PC; therefore, the smaller the better. I have already checked the specifications and that cpu Noctua cooler is compatible with the CPU that I want to buy according to this link: https://ncc.noctua.at/cpus/model/AMD-Ryzen-7-5700G-1303

**Anyways my question is:**

I want to overclock the cpu a little and am wondering if attaching a [thermoelectric Cooler Cooling Peltier Plate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rT9-HUzUqhQ&t=119s) to the sides or top will help bring down the temperature?

Or can I attach/solder [another heat sink like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NVLMZNT) to the Noctua cpu cooler will bring down the temperature?

> *I want to specifically use that Noctua nh-l12s cooler because it is small enough to the point where all my components will fit on my case. If I use a bigger cooler it will not fit. I will like to expand that cooler sideways but am not able to go much higher.*

Comment: I am trying hard to erase the mental picture of the aluminum slab somehow soldered to the cooler's fins... anyway, if you only want to overclock "a little" then fan speed control might be able to deal with it, with a price of higher noise, of course.

Comment: So attaching another heat sink to the outside metal of the Noctua metal will not work correct?

Comment: Even if we set blocked airflow aside, I have no idea how you can possibly attach it to achieve thermal conduction

Comment: if you get lucky you can change to fan for a model with higher air flow rating. The Mianboard will be plug'n'play but you get this extra of cooling. Maybe bigger in size (the square + 10mm) and some fancy hot-glue? Or a industrial type with higher rpm (more noise) or or or or...

Comment: I would avoid the TEC. You might get condensation on the cool side which will give you bigger problems than overheating. And you have to ask yourself where the heat from the hot side is going to go.